# Is there a Django function to count objects even on None objects?

Tags: python, django

Is there a Django built-in function which returns the number of items in a queryset and returns 0 if the object is None?

What I expect:

```
thefunction([obj1, obj2])
>>> 2
obj1 = None
thefunction(obj1)
>>> 0
```

I tried `len()` python function, and `count()` Django method, but they does not work on `None` objects (I understand this behaviour).

If there is no such a method, I will write it by myself, just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

EDIT : I wrote it by myself, but I still would like to know (to learn) if this function exists or not in Python :)

```
def len_none(iterable):
    ''' Return the len of an object, and 0 if object is None or empty '''
    if iterable: # object exists and is not empty
        return len(iterable)
    else:
        return 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: I dont believe there is any function builtin. However, if you are using a `MyModel.objects.none()`, you would not need the check. One way to ascertain the iterable, `if hasattr(qs, '__iter__'): return len(qs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `len` on a queryset will return `0` if it's empty. A queryset will not return `None` for an empty queryset. For example, if I had `5` images:

```
>>> len(Images.objects.none()) == 0
True
>>> len(Images.objects.all()) == 5
True
```

I don't think there's anything to do specifcally what you're asking, but there are many ways to achieve it. Here's one:

```
>>> one = [1, 2, 3]
>>> two = None
>>> len(one or [])
3
>>> len(two or [])
0
```

Comment: The thing is I don't call it on empty queryset :) (I know it's an unusual case). thanks for `len(obj or [])` syntax, very pythonic :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write your own:

```
def my_count(var):
    try:
        return count(var)
    except TypeError:
        return 0
```

Comment: thanks, I know how to write this function :) The question is just to know if it already exists or not (to avoid writing functions that already exist in my code). I updated my question to make it more clear. Thanks.